# How to find I(t)?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, current-measurement, short-circuit, step-response

[image]

so I'm trying to find the current I(t) passing through the node above the switch.
I have already found the DC response of the RC circuit which is

[image]

in the form of:

[image]

so, after the switch closes a short circuit will be created, and here is the confusion, is the current going to take the shorter path ignoring the 4k resistor and the 12V source and no current will flow through them? with that being said, I don't know whether to consider them in my calculation of I(t)
What should I do?

Comment: why would you think that the 4 k resistor would have no current flowing through it if you applied 12 V across it?

Comment: @jsotola I think what he means to say is no part of his current of interest, i(t), flows through the 4k resistor when the switch is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After the switch closes:**
You always have to consider everything that will have an effect. In this case, the perfect short basically makes the left and right current loops independent of each other which means that the 12V will no affect the 36V. Write out the loop equations and you will see. There is no component that will have both currents from both halves running through it and therefore no voltage drop is dependent on both loops. And the only thing that carries over from before the switch closes is the cap voltage which is an initial condition.

Comment: Should take -1 (I didn't): The 12V loop has big impact on initial voltage of capacitor (while switch is open).

Comment: @VillageTech It's not talking about when the switch is open. It's talking about after the switch is closed hence my mention about the perfect short which is also the scenario specifically requested for in the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, but after closing, the I(t) depends on initial conditions.

Comment: @VillageTech And? I already covered that. Are you getting confused because the first paragraph talks about when the switch is open and the second paragraph talks about when the switch is closed?

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't understand your comment - but it simply seems to be not clear ;) And - as I wrote - I didn't downvote you.

Comment: @VillageTech I'll try and clarify it.

Comment: so, I should treat the 12V voltage source and the 4k resistor as another independent circuit? And regarding the equation, the equation was found was for the interval t > 0, and only the initial voltage was taken from the interval before the switch closes, V(0) = 32v. According to the equation, the final cap voltage is 27v while the initial voltage is 32v. To find the final voltage, i assumed the capacitor is now fully charged and opened the cap branch. after combining the resistors and doing source transformation, the voltage will be v = 18mA*1.5k = 27V. I can't see where the mistake is

Comment: @Obada Oh okay. I'll remove that part of my answer since I misinterpreted what that equation was in your post. Something was weird with that simulation result too since I couldn't reproduce it. I must have misread a value since I checked it by hand too. I don't know what happened. The new simulation matches your voltages.

Comment: @Obada After the switch closes, you can treat the 12V/4k as an independent circuit as far as your i(t) is concerned since all of your i(t) will bypass it through the perfect short that is the switch and since there are no components in series with the switch there are no voltage drops to affect the KVL loop for the 12V/4k. You can't do this before the switch closes though, obviously.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did. My brain combined the 6K and 4K as a 1K resistor in the simulation instead of a 10K and then I continued to use 1K even in the hand calculations

Comment: well, that settles it, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You have an equation for the voltage across the capacitor as a function of time. After the switch closes, the 6kΩ resistor is in parallel with the capacitor. That should be enough information for you to find \$i(t)\$